# Cosmic Expansion - Why aren't we ripped off yet?

Tags: cosmology, universe, space-expansion, big-bang, dark-energy

According to Hubble's law, the universe expands exponentially ever since the big bang.

1. If the space-time expands, what effects does it have upon us, (1.Earth, 2.solar system and 3. Milky Way).
2. What would be the fate of Gravitational force and other forces of nature if the expansion continues.
3. What happens to the dark energy and dark matter then?
4. Won't all the dark energy be used up in the acceleration process?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does space expansion not expand matter?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2110/)

Comment: The universe hasn't been expanding exponentially since the Big Bang. For the first half of its life it was expanding as roughly $t^{2/3}$, and the exponential contribution to the expansion only became significant around 6 billion years ago. However the future expansion will tend towards exponential as the density of matter dilutes towards zero.